# What is the correct procedure to split the Data sets for classification problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm, train-test-split

I am new to Machine Learning & Deep Learning. I would like to clarify my doubt related to `train_test_split` before training

I have a data set of size `(302, 100, 5)`, where,

`(207,100,5)` belongs to `class 0`

`(95,100,5)`  belongs to `class 1.`

I would like to perform Classification using LSTM (since, sequence Data)

How can i split my data set for training, since the classes do
not have equal distribution sets ?

**Option  1** : Consider whole data `[(302,100, 5) - both classes (0 & 1)]`, shuffle it, train_test_split,
proceed training.

**Option 2 :** Split both class data set equally
`[(95,100,5) - class 0 & (95,100,5) - class 1]`, shuffle it,
train_test_split, proceed training.

What will be the better way of splitting before training, so that i can get better results in terms of loss reduction, accuracy, prediction, ?

If there are other options rather than above 2 options, kindly recommend,

**Based on the comment section i include a part of my data :**

**X_train : shape (241 * 100 * 5)**

Each row in every 100*5 corresponds to 1 Time step
Finally 100 rows corresponds to 100 Time steps in milli seconds (ms)

```html
array([[[0.98620635, 0.        , 0.12752912, 0.60897341, 0.46903766],
        [0.97345112, 0.        , 0.12752912, 0.49205995, 0.38709902],
        [0.9566397 , 0.        , 0.12752912, 0.45728718, 0.42154812],
        ...,
        [0.28669754, 0.8852459 , 0.12752912, 0.8786213 , 0.80125523],
        [0.31559784, 0.8852459 , 0.20968731, 0.89087803, 0.79476987],
        [0.34368841, 0.8852459 , 0.12752912, 0.89087803, 0.71066946]],

       [[0.97957188, 0.14909194, 0.04159147, 0.50548561, 0.34209531],
        [0.9687237 , 0.13964397, 0.04159147, 0.55926067, 0.64613533],
        [0.96596236, 0.13553813, 0.04159147, 0.55903796, 0.85299319],
        ...,
        [0.49309139, 0.72396527, 0.04159147, 0.81998825, 0.12362443],
        [0.52072591, 0.70872926, 0.04159147, 0.82361951, 0.89639432],
        [0.54441507, 0.71835207, 0.04159147, 0.84964602, 1.        ]],

       [[0.48151381, 0.875     , 0.16666667, 0.90637286, 0.62737926],
        [0.53325374, 0.8625    , 0.33333333, 0.87881677, 0.5321154 ],
        [0.57506452, 0.81859091, 0.16666667, 0.84915758, 0.3552661 ],
        ...,
        [0.34456041, 0.92993213, 0.33333333, 0.92953899, 0.78782408],
        [0.39496018, 0.90523485, 0.33333333, 0.9117954 , 0.54579383],
        [0.44187985, 0.8625    , 0.33333333, 0.84163194, 0.25789356]],

       ...,

       [[0.16368355, 0.        , 0.15313225, 0.40101906, 0.36784741],
        [0.15679684, 0.        , 0.15313225, 0.4435126 , 0.67351994],
        [0.15544309, 0.06132052, 0.15313225, 0.40101906, 0.36611345],
        ...,
        [0.43936628, 0.68292683, 0.15313225, 0.82305329, 0.36784741],
        [0.49751546, 0.68292683, 0.07764888, 0.84141109, 0.42828833],
        [0.53288488, 0.68292683, 0.15313225, 0.85959823, 0.36784741]],

       [[0.9418247 , 0.30821318, 0.03072816, 0.744977  , 0.93769733],
        [0.9537216 , 0.28989357, 0.03072816, 0.74576381, 0.98468743],
        [0.96455286, 0.21736423, 0.03072816, 0.74182977, 1.        ],
        ...,
        [0.36273884, 0.60113245, 0.06145633, 0.85409181, 0.32277415],
        [0.38774614, 0.57789971, 0.05844559, 0.82937631, 0.        ],
        [0.41546859, 0.57789971, 0.03072816, 0.79315883, 0.31256578]],

       [[0.97868688, 0.06451613, 0.00411829, 0.64705259, 0.69827586],
        [0.97999663, 0.06451613, 0.02256676, 0.66812232, 0.75195925],
        [0.97143037, 0.02476377, 0.02256676, 0.66317859, 0.78487461],
        ...,
        [0.50336862, 0.73867709, 0.02256676, 0.84921606, 0.1226489 ],
        [0.54003486, 0.72043011, 0.02256676, 0.82679269, 0.20297806],
        [0.57594039, 0.70967742, 0.02256676, 0.83350205, 0.        ]]])
```

**Y_train : shape (241,)**

```html
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.
 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.
 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.
 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1.
 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1.
 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.
 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.
 1.]
```

**For reference**, 
As you can see above, X-train data is large, I cannot include complete set of my entire X_train data.  So I provide only one segment of my data here for better understanding of how my data looks like for 1 segment, `(i.e X_train[0] : shape- (100*5))`. The remaining `240` will more or less looks like below

```html
array([[9.86206354e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 2.29139335e-02,
        6.08973407e-01, 4.69037657e-01],
       [9.73451120e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 2.60807671e-02,
        4.92059955e-01, 3.87099024e-01],
       [9.56639704e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 2.64184174e-02,
        4.57287179e-01, 4.21548117e-01],
       [9.34897700e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 2.64184174e-02,
        4.84177685e-01, 4.69037657e-01],
       [9.18030989e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 2.64184174e-02,
        4.86406180e-01, 4.08577406e-01],
       [9.02168015e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 2.64020795e-02,
        4.84920517e-01, 4.04184100e-01],
       [8.82551572e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 2.56783096e-02,
        4.51195959e-01, 3.78661088e-01],
       [8.69975342e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 2.40477851e-02,
        4.70286733e-01, 4.23640167e-01],
       [8.41027241e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 1.75387576e-02,
        5.04754123e-01, 4.34728033e-01],
       [8.28189535e-01, 5.28763040e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 6.89133486e-03,
        4.98662903e-01, 4.58368201e-01],
       [8.21784739e-01, 8.21162444e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 1.06196483e-02,
        5.87431288e-01, 5.72594142e-01],
       [8.26651597e-01, 9.96721311e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 1.75044480e-02,
        6.89050661e-01, 5.40376569e-01],
       [8.42115326e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 1.71205069e-02,
        8.35388501e-01, 4.69037657e-01],
       [8.64071009e-01, 9.26875310e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 1.34068975e-02,
        1.00000000e+00, 4.65062762e-01],
       [8.79579724e-01, 7.60158967e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 4.65303975e-03,
        9.61744169e-01, 3.65481172e-01],
       [9.03630040e-01, 7.61549925e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 4.21518348e-03,
        9.22076957e-01, 3.78033473e-01],
       [9.18435858e-01, 6.72429210e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 2.70229205e-03,
        9.39979201e-01, 5.03138075e-01],
       [9.29983046e-01, 6.85345256e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 9.05120794e-04,
        8.53736443e-01, 5.52510460e-01],
       [9.48081232e-01, 5.78539493e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 6.96485550e-03,
        8.84415391e-01, 3.04602510e-01],
       [9.48112160e-01, 5.55091903e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 1.10493356e-02,
        8.19046204e-01, 4.78661088e-01],
       [9.61281634e-01, 5.08693492e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 9.36162843e-03,
        8.23651761e-01, 3.21548117e-01],
       [9.72179346e-01, 4.91803279e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 9.82725917e-03,
        7.57391175e-01, 4.96025105e-01],
       [9.84752763e-01, 4.91803279e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 7.04491131e-03,
        7.59322538e-01, 3.95397490e-01],
       [9.90300024e-01, 4.91803279e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 8.19346712e-03,
        7.64819492e-01, 4.69037657e-01],
       [9.88306609e-01, 3.77049180e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 8.62642201e-03,
        7.93492795e-01, 4.16945607e-01],
       [9.91084457e-01, 3.93442623e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 9.16557339e-03,
        7.10741346e-01, 4.72175732e-01],
       [1.00000000e+00, 3.78936910e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 1.16538387e-02,
        6.93359085e-01, 4.76987448e-01],
       [9.98925974e-01, 3.93442623e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 1.21309060e-02,
        7.16609716e-01, 3.46025105e-01],
       [9.92838888e-01, 3.32141083e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 1.19315833e-02,
        7.31540633e-01, 4.16527197e-01],
       [9.90637415e-01, 3.36910084e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 9.95632874e-03,
        7.12524142e-01, 4.15481172e-01],
       [9.90761125e-01, 3.38301043e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 6.59235091e-03,
        6.86970732e-01, 4.37656904e-01],
       [9.90274720e-01, 3.27868852e-01, 2.10913550e-01, 5.68396253e-03,
        7.09181399e-01, 4.99372385e-01],
       [9.83015202e-01, 3.27868852e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 2.14974358e-02,
        7.31392067e-01, 6.41631799e-01],
       [9.77392028e-01, 2.85245902e-01, 1.47762109e-01, 2.52861995e-02,
        7.09478532e-01, 6.07112971e-01],
       [9.75300207e-01, 2.78688525e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 2.91468501e-02,
        6.70257020e-01, 6.28242678e-01],
       [9.74917831e-01, 2.71733731e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 3.58780734e-02,
        6.70257020e-01, 5.72594142e-01],
       [9.64950755e-01, 2.62295082e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 3.92992339e-02,
        6.36383895e-01, 6.67991632e-01],
       [9.63159774e-01, 2.62295082e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 4.82932591e-02,
        6.93581934e-01, 5.46443515e-01],
       [9.54983679e-01, 2.90511674e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 4.90627752e-02,
        6.59708810e-01, 7.40376569e-01],
       [9.57595643e-01, 3.11475410e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 4.72492660e-02,
        6.49977715e-01, 5.61297071e-01],
       [9.51511369e-01, 2.95081967e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 1.82576261e-02,
        6.64314366e-01, 5.22384937e-01],
       [9.48528275e-01, 2.95081967e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 3.89659403e-03,
        6.29846977e-01, 3.20711297e-01],
       [9.47085931e-01, 2.95081967e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 6.86682798e-03,
        6.48417769e-01, 4.38284519e-01],
       [9.38153518e-01, 2.95081967e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 5.73951146e-03,
        7.04130144e-01, 5.32635983e-01],
       [9.38114156e-01, 2.95081967e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 2.05955826e-02,
        6.85782202e-01, 5.47280335e-01],
       [9.35597786e-01, 2.95081967e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 2.91141743e-02,
        6.69142772e-01, 7.13807531e-01],
       [9.29311077e-01, 2.72826627e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 2.91141743e-02,
        6.81622344e-01, 5.72594142e-01],
       [9.25495753e-01, 2.23646299e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 2.65507546e-02,
        6.35566781e-01, 6.41004184e-01],
       [9.18525829e-01, 2.08643815e-03, 1.27529123e-01, 2.37618715e-02,
        6.09641955e-01, 5.02928870e-01],
       [8.91801693e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 9.27013608e-03,
        5.26073392e-01, 4.21338912e-01],
       [8.77693149e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 8.13628440e-03,
        4.22522656e-01, 3.44560669e-01],
       [8.61894841e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 1.49639014e-02,
        4.52755906e-01, 3.65481172e-01],
       [8.44254943e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 2.29515107e-02,
        4.59069975e-01, 3.76150628e-01],
       [8.21183060e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 3.97583295e-02,
        4.60852771e-01, 2.60460251e-01],
       [8.04116726e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 5.89292454e-02,
        4.26905363e-01, 1.97907950e-01],
       [7.81311943e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 8.53656345e-02,
        4.37379290e-01, 1.00836820e-01],
       [7.60863270e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 1.03087377e-01,
        4.37379290e-01, 6.98744770e-02],
       [7.41227145e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 1.14206966e-01,
        4.27128213e-01, 1.58368201e-01],
       [7.26694052e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 1.17776801e-01,
        4.37379290e-01, 0.00000000e+00],
       [7.08716764e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 1.17288297e-01,
        4.48596048e-01, 2.18619247e-01],
       [6.90483621e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 1.08491961e-01,
        4.58549993e-01, 1.26987448e-01],
       [6.67451099e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 8.38217010e-02,
        4.99628584e-01, 3.55020921e-01],
       [6.51610618e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 4.32889541e-02,
        5.10919626e-01, 4.83054393e-01],
       [6.31195684e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 1.29200275e-02,
        5.21170703e-01, 4.97907950e-01],
       [6.14317726e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.26241570e-01, 9.32895259e-04,
        4.98960036e-01, 4.69037657e-01],
       [5.98165158e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 5.90435316e-01, 0.00000000e+00,
        4.61892735e-01, 5.03556485e-01],
       [5.68221755e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 6.33353771e-01, 1.61745413e-03,
        4.25122567e-01, 4.69037657e-01],
       [5.35292447e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 8.99402522e-03,
        3.58490566e-01, 5.10041841e-01],
       [5.10766973e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 3.93010423e-01, 3.39894098e-02,
        3.27068786e-01, 6.15690377e-01],
       [4.78939807e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 5.32188841e-01, 5.98114931e-02,
        3.27068786e-01, 6.22175732e-01],
       [4.47053597e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 4.31023912e-01, 8.44245703e-02,
        3.24023176e-01, 6.76150628e-01],
       [4.13654754e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 5.32188841e-01, 1.07209434e-01,
        2.90298618e-01, 7.08577406e-01],
       [3.80151882e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 7.97057020e-01, 1.21122807e-01,
        1.19150201e-01, 4.95397490e-01],
       [3.28235926e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 3.56223176e-01, 1.23820198e-01,
        0.00000000e+00, 6.65271967e-01],
       [2.83452966e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.28694053e-01, 1.22658572e-01,
        2.65933739e-02, 5.55648536e-01],
       [2.38616587e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.28694053e-01, 1.22990232e-01,
        9.41910563e-02, 4.92887029e-01],
       [1.82964031e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 5.19926426e-01, 1.30564491e-01,
        8.97340663e-02, 4.94142259e-01],
       [1.43835174e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 5.25444513e-01, 1.64135650e-01,
        1.14618927e-01, 7.40585774e-01],
       [1.04402664e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.55119559e-01, 2.41378071e-01,
        1.98261774e-01, 6.50418410e-01],
       [7.96438281e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 7.11220110e-02, 3.27145618e-01,
        2.89110088e-01, 7.45188285e-01],
       [6.36065353e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 4.11129065e-01,
        4.05140395e-01, 6.88912134e-01],
       [4.11672585e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 2.52605763e-01, 5.62182942e-01,
        4.54315852e-01, 1.00000000e+00],
       [2.87063044e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 1.27529123e-01, 6.81786323e-01,
        4.59515674e-01, 9.32217573e-01],
       [1.70269716e-02, 1.58966716e-03, 1.27529123e-01, 7.33474602e-01,
        4.37453573e-01, 6.07322176e-01],
       [3.30361486e-03, 6.37853949e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 8.06276376e-01,
        4.69692468e-01, 7.54602510e-01],
       [0.00000000e+00, 7.89369101e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 8.85843682e-01,
        5.10919626e-01, 8.70502092e-01],
       [5.13114648e-03, 8.19672131e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 9.60932765e-01,
        5.99316595e-01, 8.79288703e-01],
       [2.16829598e-02, 8.36065574e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 9.99121020e-01,
        7.28866439e-01, 8.56903766e-01],
       [4.27951674e-02, 8.36065574e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 1.00000000e+00,
        8.67181697e-01, 7.88912134e-01],
       [7.02334461e-02, 8.36065574e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 9.93500775e-01,
        8.46308127e-01, 9.78451883e-01],
       [9.73680733e-02, 8.36065574e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 9.87896869e-01,
        8.66364582e-01, 8.59414226e-01],
       [1.23611427e-01, 8.36065574e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 9.69613102e-01,
        8.35685634e-01, 9.17991632e-01],
       [1.52157471e-01, 8.68852459e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 9.22226597e-01,
        7.96686971e-01, 9.65062762e-01],
       [1.77979087e-01, 8.68852459e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 8.61132577e-01,
        8.29594414e-01, 8.14225941e-01],
       [2.03010647e-01, 8.84252360e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 8.13277174e-01,
        8.29594414e-01, 9.11506276e-01],
       [2.32490138e-01, 8.85245902e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 7.59549923e-01,
        8.41851137e-01, 9.52301255e-01],
       [2.58952796e-01, 8.85245902e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 6.97804020e-01,
        8.55667806e-01, 8.68200837e-01],
       [2.86697538e-01, 8.85245902e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 6.25149288e-01,
        8.78621304e-01, 8.01255230e-01],
       [3.15597842e-01, 8.85245902e-01, 2.09687308e-01, 5.51940700e-01,
        8.90878027e-01, 7.94769874e-01],
       [3.43688409e-01, 8.85245902e-01, 1.27529123e-01, 4.75801089e-01,
        8.90878027e-01, 7.10669456e-01]])
```

Comment: have you explored the stratify option in train test split ?

Comment: No @venkatakrishnan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** Try both!

---

I have been in similar situations before where my dataset was imbalanced. I used [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split) or [KFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold) to get through.

However, once I stumbled upon the problem of handling imbalanced datasets and came across the techniques of overbalancing and underbalancing. To do this, I would recommend using the library: [imblearn](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/)

You will find various techniques there to handle the cases where one of your classes outnumbers the other one. I personally have used [SMOTE](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html?highlight=smote) a lot and have had relatively better success in such cases.

---

Other references:

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/imbalanced-classification-problem/

https://towardsdatascience.com/handling-imbalanced-datasets-in-machine-learning-7a0e84220f28

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, have you tried SMOTE for higher D (dimensional)  data. Since I am working with 5 features here ?

Comment: I had anywhere between 10 and 30 features I would say. However, it doesnt hurt to try, experiment and see how the model behaves :)

Comment: Sure I will try and let you know :)

Comment: I have been working with LSTM which contains `X_train shape : (241 * 100 * 4)` and `Y-train shape : (241)`. In that case whether my **SMOTE sampling support** for 3D array  ???? Or  SMOTE support for only 2D array ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stratify option in train test split, which splits each class on the mentioned test size.

```
x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,stratify=y)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a project where I am experimenting with credit dataset(imbalanced dataset containing 1% of a minority class and 99% of the majority class) for fraud detection using different sampling method and found that SMOTE gives better results with imbalanced datasets.

SMOTE (Synthetic Minority Oversampling Technique) is a powerful sampling method that goes beyond simple under or oversampling. This algorithm creates new instances of the minority class by creating convex combinations of neighbouring instances

I have used SMOTE sampling methods along with the K-Fold cross-validation. Cross-validation technique assures that model gets the correct patterns from the data, and it is not getting up too much noise.

In the case of an imbalanced dataset, the accuracy score of sampling algorithm yields an accuracy of 99% which seems impressive, but minority class could be totally ignored in case of imbalanced datasets. So, I have used Matthew Coefficient Correlation Score, F1 Score measuring algorithm in addition to Accuracy for performance measurement on an Imbalanced Dataset.

Code :

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, 
random_state=0)

sm = SMOTE(random_state=2)
X_train_res, y_train_res = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train.ravel())
```

References :

https://www.kaggle.com/qianchao/smote-with-imbalance-data

Comment: I have been working with LSTM which contains `X_train shape : (241 * 100 * 4)` and `Y-train shape : (241)`. In that case whether my **SMOTE sampling support** for 3D array  ???? Or  SMOTE support for only 2D array ?

Comment: I didn't try on 2d but It's look like Smote work on 2d. Please refer below link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56125380/resampling-data-using-smote-from-imblearn-with-3d-numpy-arrays

Comment: I have checked the link, but I am not sure it will work in my case. My  `X_train shape : (241 * 100 * 4)` each `(100*4)` belongs to class `0 or 1`. **If i reshape then there is no point of doing SMOTE sampling**

Comment: Please share some sample data.

Comment: Please refer to my question. I have added my data. @SUN